# How do I add a While loop to this program I would like it to be able to repeat?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I am trying to get the program to be able to repeat over and over again I can't seem to get the while loop to work and I am not sure how to structure it with a while loop. This program calculates the heat transfer between different objects. I have tried adding a while loop at the beginning but the program still does not repeat

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>


int main()
{
    //Variables
    char userName [50];
    int choice;        /*Material picked by the user*/
    double thickness;   /* "th" Thickness of the material in question*/
    double surfaceArea; /* "a" Surface Area of the wall in ft^2*/
    double temp1;       /* "t1" Temperature of wall 1 in Fahrenheit*/
    double temp2;       /* "t2" Temperature of wall 2 in Fahrenheit*/
    double heatTransfer; /* "h" The heat transfer rate in BTU/hr*/
    /*Variable k, which is a constant, will be defined for each material in the materials own processing*/
    
    //Prompting for Name
    printf("Hello, welcome to the Heat Trasnfer Program! Could you please input your name: "); /*prompting name of user*/
    scanf("%s",  userName);
    printf("\nHello %s, with what can I help you today? The menu is down below:\n\n", userName);/*prompting to get them ready for the menu.*/
    
    //Menu that's displayed on screen
    printf("Heat Transfer Menu:\n");
    printf("\tMaterials:\t\t \n");
    printf("\t1. Hardwood Siding\t\t \n");
    printf("\t2. Concrete Block\t\t\n");
    printf("\t3. Styrofoam\t\t\t \n");
    printf("\t4. Fiberglass\t\t\t \n");
    printf("\t5. Drywall\t\t\t \n");
    printf("\t6. Quit.\n\n");
    
    //Gathering Material that will be worked with
    printf("Please input your material choice number: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    
    //Testing Choice to see if it's a valid input
    if (choice == 1)
    {
        printf("\nYou chose the material Hardwood Siding.\n");/*Verifying that the material is correct*/
        printf("\nWhat is the thickness of the Hardwood Siding in feet?: ");
        scanf("%lf", &thickness);
        printf("What is the surface area of the Hardwood Siding wall in ft?: ");
        scanf("%lf", &surfaceArea);
        printf("What about the temperature of wall 1 in Fahrenheit?: ");
        scanf("%lf", &temp1);
        printf("What about the temperature of wall 2 in Fahrenheit?: ");
        scanf("%lf", &temp2);
        //Processing the Heat Transfer of Hardwood Siding with a k of 0.092
        heatTransfer = surfaceArea*((temp2 - temp1)/(thickness/0.092));
        printf("\nThe heat transfer rate of Hardwood Siding is %lf BTU/hr.", heatTransfer);
    }
    else if (choice == 2)
    {
        printf("\nYou chose the material Concrete Block.\n");
        printf("\nWhat is the thickness of the Concrete Block in feet?: ");
        scanf("%lf", &thickness);
        printf("What is the surface area of the Concrete Block wall in ft?: ");
        scanf("%lf", &surfaceArea);
        printf("What about the temperature of wall 1 in Fahrenheit?: ");
        scanf("%lf", &temp1);
        printf("What about the temperature of wall 2 in Fahrenheit?: ");
        scanf("%lf", &temp2);
        //Processing the Heat Transfer of Concrete Block with k 0.260
        heatTransfer = surfaceArea*((temp2 - temp1)/(thickness/0.260));
        printf("\nThe heat transfer rate of Concrete Block with a thickness of %lf, a surface area of %lf, and with temperatures of %lf and %lf is %lf BTU/hr.", thickness, surfaceArea, temp1, temp2, heatTransfer);
    }
    else if (choice == 3)
    {
        printf("\nYou chose the material Styrofoam.\n");
        printf("\nWhat is the thickness of the Styrofoam in feet?: ");
        scanf("%lf", &thickness);
        printf("What is the surface area of the Styrofoam wall in ft?: ");
        scanf("%lf", &surfaceArea);
        printf("What about the temperature of wall 1 in Fahrenheit?: ");
        scanf("%lf", &temp1);
        printf("What about the temperature of wall 2 in Fahrenheit?: ");
        scanf("%lf", &temp2);
        //Processing the Heat Transfer of Styrofoam with a k of 0.017
        heatTransfer = surfaceArea*((temp2 - temp1)/(thickness/0.017));
        printf("\nThe heat transfer rate of Styrofoam with a thickness of %lf, a surface area of %lf, and with temperatures of %lf and %lf is %lf BTU/hr.", thickness, surfaceArea, temp1, temp2, heatTransfer);
    }
    else if (choice == 4)
    {
        printf("\nYou chose the material Fiberglass.\n");
        printf("\nWhat is the thickness of the Fiberglass in feet?: ");
        scanf("%lf", &thickness);
        printf("What is the surface area of the Fiberglass wall in ft?: ");
        scanf("%lf", &surfaceArea);
        printf("What about the temperature of wall 1 in Fahrenheit?: ");
        scanf("%lf", &temp1);
        printf("What about the temperature of wall 2 in Fahrenheit?: ");
        scanf("%lf", &temp2);
        //Processing the Heat Transfer of Fiberglass with a k of 0.027
        heatTransfer = surfaceArea*((temp2 - temp1)/(thickness/0.027));
        printf("\nThe heat transfer rate of Fiberglass with a thickness of %lf, a surface area of %lf, and with temperatures of %lf and %lf is %lf BTU/hr.", thickness, surfaceArea, temp1, temp2, heatTransfer);
    }
    else if (choice == 5)
    {
        printf("\nYou chose the material Drywall.\n");
        printf("What is the thickness of the Drywall in feet?: ");
        scanf("%lf", &thickness);
        printf("What is the surface area of the Drywall wall in ft?: ");
        scanf("%lf", &surfaceArea);
        printf("What about the temperature of wall 1 in Fahrenheit?: ");
        scanf("%lf", &temp1);
        printf("What about the temperature of wall 2 in Fahrenheit?: ");
        scanf("%lf", &temp2);
        //Processing the Heat Transfer of Drywall with a k of 0.093
        heatTransfer = surfaceArea*((temp2 - temp1)/(thickness/0.093));
        printf("\nThe heat transfer rate of the Drywall with a thickness of %lf, a surface area of %lf, and with temperatures of %lf and %lf is %lf BTU/hr.", thickness, surfaceArea, temp1, temp2, heatTransfer);
    }
    else if (choice == 6)
    {
        printf("\nThank you! Bye bye %s.\n", userName);
    }
    
    //Output
    printf("\n\n\nThank you for using this program %s, bye bye.", userName);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You *must* *always* check the value returned by scanf.  `int choice; scanf("%d", &choice); if( choice ==1 )` is undefined behavior if the input stream contains an 'a', since choice is uninitialized and scanf doesn't assign to it.

Answer (score 0):

You have two several choices to archive the goal. The code below uses the first one.

- `while (true)`/`for(;;)` and `break`
- `do{} while();`

```cpp
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  // Variables
  char userName[50];
  int choice;          /*Material picked by the user*/
  double thickness;    /* "th" Thickness of the material in question*/
  double surfaceArea;  /* "a" Surface Area of the wall in ft^2*/
  double temp1;        /* "t1" Temperature of wall 1 in Fahrenheit*/
  double temp2;        /* "t2" Temperature of wall 2 in Fahrenheit*/
  double heatTransfer; /* "h" The heat transfer rate in BTU/hr*/
  /*Variable k, which is a constant, will be defined for each material in the
   * materials own processing*/
  while (true) {
    // Prompting for Name
    printf(
        "Hello, welcome to the Heat Trasnfer Program! Could you please input "
        "your name: "); /*prompting name of user*/
    scanf("%s", userName);
    printf(
        "\nHello %s, with what can I help you today? The menu is down "
        "below:\n\n",
        userName); /*prompting to get them ready for the menu.*/

    // Menu that's displayed on screen
    printf("Heat Transfer Menu:\n");
    printf("\tMaterials:\t\t \n");
    printf("\t1. Hardwood Siding\t\t \n");
    printf("\t2. Concrete Block\t\t\n");
    printf("\t3. Styrofoam\t\t\t \n");
    printf("\t4. Fiberglass\t\t\t \n");
    printf("\t5. Drywall\t\t\t \n");
    printf("\t6. Quit.\n\n");

    // Gathering Material that will be worked with
    printf("Please input your material choice number: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    // Testing Choice to see if it's a valid input
    if (choice == 1) {
      printf("\nYou chose the material Hardwood Siding.\n"); /*Verifying that
                                                                the material is
                                                                correct*/
      printf("\nWhat is the thickness of the Hardwood Siding in feet?: ");
      scanf("%lf", &thickness);
      printf("What is the surface area of the Hardwood Siding wall in ft?: ");
      scanf("%lf", &surfaceArea);
      printf("What about the temperature of wall 1 in Fahrenheit?: ");
      scanf("%lf", &temp1);
      printf("What about the temperature of wall 2 in Fahrenheit?: ");
      scanf("%lf", &temp2);
      // Processing the Heat Transfer of Hardwood Siding with a k of 0.092
      heatTransfer = surfaceArea * ((temp2 - temp1) / (thickness / 0.092));
      printf("\nThe heat transfer rate of Hardwood Siding is %lf BTU/hr.",
             heatTransfer);
    } else if (choice == 2) {
      printf("\nYou chose the material Concrete Block.\n");
      printf("\nWhat is the thickness of the Concrete Block in feet?: ");
      scanf("%lf", &thickness);
      printf("What is the surface area of the Concrete Block wall in ft?: ");
      scanf("%lf", &surfaceArea);
      printf("What about the temperature of wall 1 in Fahrenheit?: ");
      scanf("%lf", &temp1);
      printf("What about the temperature of wall 2 in Fahrenheit?: ");
      scanf("%lf", &temp2);
      // Processing the Heat Transfer of Concrete Block with k 0.260
      heatTransfer = surfaceArea * ((temp2 - temp1) / (thickness / 0.260));
      printf(
          "\nThe heat transfer rate of Concrete Block with a thickness of %lf, "
          "a "
          "surface area of %lf, and with temperatures of %lf and %lf is %lf "
          "BTU/hr.",
          thickness, surfaceArea, temp1, temp2, heatTransfer);
    } else if (choice == 3) {
      printf("\nYou chose the material Styrofoam.\n");
      printf("\nWhat is the thickness of the Styrofoam in feet?: ");
      scanf("%lf", &thickness);
      printf("What is the surface area of the Styrofoam wall in ft?: ");
      scanf("%lf", &surfaceArea);
      printf("What about the temperature of wall 1 in Fahrenheit?: ");
      scanf("%lf", &temp1);
      printf("What about the temperature of wall 2 in Fahrenheit?: ");
      scanf("%lf", &temp2);
      // Processing the Heat Transfer of Styrofoam with a k of 0.017
      heatTransfer = surfaceArea * ((temp2 - temp1) / (thickness / 0.017));
      printf(
          "\nThe heat transfer rate of Styrofoam with a thickness of %lf, a "
          "surface area of %lf, and with temperatures of %lf and %lf is %lf "
          "BTU/hr.",
          thickness, surfaceArea, temp1, temp2, heatTransfer);
    } else if (choice == 4) {
      printf("\nYou chose the material Fiberglass.\n");
      printf("\nWhat is the thickness of the Fiberglass in feet?: ");
      scanf("%lf", &thickness);
      printf("What is the surface area of the Fiberglass wall in ft?: ");
      scanf("%lf", &surfaceArea);
      printf("What about the temperature of wall 1 in Fahrenheit?: ");
      scanf("%lf", &temp1);
      printf("What about the temperature of wall 2 in Fahrenheit?: ");
      scanf("%lf", &temp2);
      // Processing the Heat Transfer of Fiberglass with a k of 0.027
      heatTransfer = surfaceArea * ((temp2 - temp1) / (thickness / 0.027));
      printf(
          "\nThe heat transfer rate of Fiberglass with a thickness of %lf, a "
          "surface area of %lf, and with temperatures of %lf and %lf is %lf "
          "BTU/hr.",
          thickness, surfaceArea, temp1, temp2, heatTransfer);
    } else if (choice == 5) {
      printf("\nYou chose the material Drywall.\n");
      printf("What is the thickness of the Drywall in feet?: ");
      scanf("%lf", &thickness);
      printf("What is the surface area of the Drywall wall in ft?: ");
      scanf("%lf", &surfaceArea);
      printf("What about the temperature of wall 1 in Fahrenheit?: ");
      scanf("%lf", &temp1);
      printf("What about the temperature of wall 2 in Fahrenheit?: ");
      scanf("%lf", &temp2);
      // Processing the Heat Transfer of Drywall with a k of 0.093
      heatTransfer = surfaceArea * ((temp2 - temp1) / (thickness / 0.093));
      printf(
          "\nThe heat transfer rate of the Drywall with a thickness of %lf, a "
          "surface area of %lf, and with temperatures of %lf and %lf is %lf "
          "BTU/hr.",
          thickness, surfaceArea, temp1, temp2, heatTransfer);
    } else if (choice == 6) {
      printf("\nThank you! Bye bye %s.\n", userName);
      break;
    }
  }

  // Output
  printf("\n\n\nThank you for using this program %s, bye bye.\n", userName);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You really need to split the code and try identify what can be grouped together and try avoid as much duplication as possible, for instance

Lets first define the supported materials like this

```
// this is a simple map of choice index to name of material
// 0 being not applicable and switch case can take care of 
// boundary conditions allowing only 1 - 5 
const char *materials[] =
{
    "Not-applicable",
    "Hardwood Siding",
    "Concrete Block",
    "Styrofoam",
    "Fiberglass",
    "Drywall",
};
```

start defining the menu

```
// Just a menu .. and there are no read activity here
// just a write/display
void show_menu()
{
    //Menu that's displayed on screen
    printf("Heat Transfer Menu:\n");
    printf("\tMaterials:\t\t \n");
    printf("\t1. Hardwood Siding\t\t \n");
    printf("\t2. Concrete Block\t\t\n");
    printf("\t3. Styrofoam\t\t\t \n");
    printf("\t4. Fiberglass\t\t\t \n");
    printf("\t5. Drywall\t\t\t \n");
    printf("\t6. Quit.\n\n");
}
```

generate some methods for example taking user input `take_choice` and also username `get_user` that are needed to drive this menu

```
int  take_choice()
{
    int choice = -1;
    //Gathering Material that will be worked with
    printf("Please input your material choice number: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    return choice;
}



void get_user( char *username )
{
    //Prompting for Name
    printf("Hello, welcome to the Heat Trasnfer Program! Could you please input your name: "); /*prompting name of user*/
    scanf("%s",  username);
    printf("\nHello %s, with what can I help you today? The menu is down below:\n\n", username);/*prompting to get them ready for the menu.*/
}
```

we almost have everything in place just a few more to help get details about specific product lines like getting thickness, surface areas etc

```
double get_thickness(int metarial)
{
    double thickness = -1;
    printf("\nWhat is the thickness of the %s in feet?: ", materials[ metarial ]);
    scanf("%lf", &thickness);
    return thickness;
}

double get_surfaceArea(int metarial)
{
    double surfaceArea = -1;
    printf("What is the surface area of the %s wall in ft?: ", materials[ metarial ]);
    scanf("%lf", &surfaceArea);
    return surfaceArea;
}
```

---

at this point we have most pieces in place to handle final workflow, stick pieces together

```
int main()
{
    //Variables
    char userName [50];
    get_user(userName);
    

    int choice = -1;
    do
    {
        show_menu();
        choice = take_choice();
        switch ( choice )
        {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
        {
            double thickness = get_thickness( choice );
            double surfaceArea = get_surfaceArea( choice );
            if( thickness > 0 && surfaceArea > 0 )
            {
                double temp1;       /* "t1" Temperature of wall 1 in Fahrenheit*/
                printf("What about the temperature of wall 1 in Fahrenheit?: ");
                scanf("%lf", &temp1);

                double temp2;       /* "t2" Temperature of wall 2 in Fahrenheit*/
                printf("What about the temperature of wall 2 in Fahrenheit?: ");
                scanf("%lf", &temp2);


                //Processing the Heat Transfer of Hardwood Siding with a k of 0.092
                double heatTransfer = surfaceArea * ((temp2 - temp1) / (thickness / 0.092));
                printf("\nThe heat transfer rate of %s is %lf BTU/hr.\n", materials[choice], heatTransfer);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("invalid input try again .. ");
            }

        }
        break;
        case 6:
            printf("\nThank you! Bye bye %s.\n", userName);
            break;
        default:
            printf("\nWrong choice try again\n");
        }
    }
    while ( choice != 6 );


    //Output
    printf("\n\n\nThank you for using this program %s, bye bye.", userName);

    return 0;
}
```